# Unable to filter search result by a custom attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, search

I had created a custom attribute `allowed_countries` for the products
I'm able to get catalog products collections based on the values of the attribute `allowed_countries`

But when I search any product the search result is showing all the products regardless of the `addAttributeToFilter()` that i had wrote!

```
->addAttributeToFilter('hidden_countries',array('nlike'=>'%'.$current_country.'%'));
```

I had copied the `Result.php` file to  :

> ```
> local/Mage/CatalogSearch/Block
> ```

And the `_getProductCollection()` will looks like :

```
 $this->_productCollection = $this->getListBlock()->getLoadedProductCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('active_stores', array('finset'=>$store_id))
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('hidden_countries',array('nlike'=>'%'.$current_country.'%'));
```

The attribute details are :

```
$attributeOptions1 = array(
  'label'                      => $attributeLabel,
  'input'                      => 'multiselect',
  'type'                       => 'text',
  'backend'                    => 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_array',
  'frontend'                   => null,
  'source'                     => 'storeSwitcher/product_attribute_source_store',
  'global'                     => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
  'required'                   => false,
  'user_defined'               => false,
  'required'                   => false,
  'class'                      => null,
  'unique'                     => false,
  'searchable'                 => true,
  'filterable'                 => false,
  'comparable'                 => false,
  'visible_on_front'           => true,
  'visible_in_advanced_search' => true,
  'is_configurable'            => false,
  'visible'                    => true,
);
```

Please let me know : I'm doing anything wrong
**Magento 1.9**

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the option_id of the Country and use 'finset'. Below is an example using custom attribute 'allowed_countries' that worked for me.

```
$countryId = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')
  ->getAttribute('allowed_countires')
  ->getSource()
  ->getOptionId('Canada');

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('allowed_countires', array('finset', $countryId));
```

Comment: the variable $current_country have country code(s), & this is working fine with category products list page :)

Comment: Have you checked for any rewrites to this block? It is working on a fresh install using the Madison Island data. Though there are some calls to getResultCount() happening before the additional filter is applied. This places the original collection count on the page, but displays the filtered collection.